# Swift iOS - OSC Library

Tags: ios, swift, osc

Anyone knows a OSC Swift Library to integrate inside an iOS App?

I am experimenting with [this](https://github.com/cpmpercussion/MetatoneOSC) however, I am finding hard to make it work with swift.

I have added in my project a bridge-header file, the project load but cannot convert code into swift.

I want to convert the objective-C code below  into swift however I cannot find the property "messageWithAddressPattern" when I try the conversion:

```
- (IBAction)sendSliderMessage:(UISlider *)sender {
    F53OSCMessage *message = [F53OSCMessage messageWithAddressPattern:@"/slider" arguments:@[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:sender.value]]];
    [self.oscClient sendPacket:message toHost:SENDHOST onPort:SENDPORT];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm successfully using MetatoneOSC without any issue in a Swift app.

Here's some working code for sending a message:

```
let oscClient = F53OSCClient.init()
oscClient.host = "127.0.0.1"
oscClient.port = 3000

let message = F53OSCMessage(addressPattern: "/hello", arguments: [0, 1, 2])
oscClient.sendPacket(message)

print("Sent '\(message)' to \(oscClient.host):\(oscClient.port)")
```

Comment: Can I ask how you imported MetatoneOSC into your Swift Project? When I tried and added the bridging header etc., I get the `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_F53OSCClient"` error

Comment: @Alfo Here's how I ended up doing it: https://github.com/marsman12019/buzzOSC, but a better solution I came up with last week is to use Cocoapods with the OSCkit pod.

Comment: OSCkit looks great! I notice that it uses oscpack as the backend for a few functions and the code is quite readable which is a plus. 

It would actually be good to have an OSC library in pure Swift. Does anyone know of such a library?